# Can transporting bottles affect the outcome of the brew?

Tags: bottling, beginner, transport

### Background

Due to the limitations of my apartment, I decided to brew at a friend's house. Once my double IPA had finished its fermentation phases, I proceeded to bottling it. Shortly afterwards, I packed them into my car and (carefully) drove home (~15 mins).

### Question

Due to the jostling of the bottles during the drive, and the shifting that happened while carrying them up and down stairs, is it likely that this has significantly affected my brew?

More generically, **can transportation/shifting of bottled brew affect the outcome?** If so, which qualities might be affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anything it likely helped get them carbonated faster.  Assuming you let the sediment that gets stirred up by moving settle before drinking, there is no harm in moving bottles.

Comment: Agree - I've had two big house moves in the two years I've brewing - no problems moving bottles. I did avoid moving a fermentor though and this meant shortening a second ("aging") fermentation on one occasion.

Comment: Okay. I had gotten it in my head that volatility in the priming/bottling phase might affect the taste. This must have been a misconception or just misinformation I overheard.